# Deterministic algorithm for matching variables by only using restricted comparison

Tags: algorithms

The problem can be stated as the following:

Given a sequence of numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ and $b_1, \ldots, b_n$ such that $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is a permutation of $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$, find an efficient algorithm which, using only comparisons between $a_i$ and $b_j$ for some $1 \le i, j \le n$, computes the permutation $\sigma$ satisfying $b_{\sigma(i)} = a_i$ for all $1 \le i \le n$.

It's easy to see that the efficiency is $\Omega(n \log{n})$ since the sorting problem can be reduced to this problem.

The original problem I saw allowed the algorithm to be randomized. By modifying quicksort algorithm a little bit we can find the optimal algorithm. (choose a pivot $a_i$, divide all $b_j$ by checking if $b_j$ is bigger/lesser/equal than $a_i$. again choose $b_{\sigma(i)}$ and do the same thing for $a_i$s, separate all lesser/bigger numbers and do the same thing recursively)

My question is that, if we restrict the algorithm to be only deterministic, can we still find the optimal algorithm for the problem?

Sorry for my short and flawed english :D

Comment: What does it mean to restrict the algorithm to be only deterministic? Presumably the "randomized" algorithm uses a deterministic pseudo-random number generator? How would you distinguish a "deterministic" algorithm from such a "randomized" algorithm?

Comment: Just to clarify, we're not allowed to (directly) compare $a_i$ with $a_j$, or $b_i$ with $b_j$, right?  (If we can do that, it should be easy to reduce the problem back to sorting.)

Comment: @joriki Sorry for confusion. What I mean by randomized algorithm is that it uses pure "ideal" random number generator and its efficiency for a input is measured by the expected value of the time taken by the algorithm. The "randomized" algorithm's efficiency is the maximum of efficiency for all inputs can be made.

Comment: @joriki "deterministic" algorithm never uses a pure "ideal" random number generator. So it can use PRNG or whatsoever. However its efficiency is measured by the maximum of efficiency for all inputs can be made(efficiency for a input is measured by just time taken for that input).

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen Sorry for confusion again. YES :-)

Comment: It seems you're using "efficiency" in an unusual way. If the algorithm's efficiency is the maximum of the efficiency for all inputs, that would mean you're doing a best-case analysis. Don't you mean something like that the *complexity* of the algorithm is determined by the maximum of the *time* it takes for all inputs?

Comment: @joriki: I guess the problem with the quicksort-based solution is that it still has $O(n^2)$ worst case complexity, and that even with pseudo-random pivoting, one could still come up with input triggering that worst case if the pseudo-random number generator was known.  I wonder if some other sorting algorithm, with true $O(n \log n)$ time complexity even in the worst case, could be adapted similarly.

Comment: @Ilmari: Heapsort's the algorithm I'm aware of that remains $O(n\log n)$ even with perverse inputs, but I don't know how it might be adapted here.

Comment: @J.M.: There are other $O(n \log n)$ worst case sorting algorithms, such as mergesort.  There's a table of best/worst/average case performance of various sorting algorithms at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms).  But I guess it's all academic now that the original question has been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is known as “matching nuts and bolts,” posed by Alon, Blum, Fiat, Kannan, Naor, and Ostrovsky [ABF+94].  It was solved by Komlós, Ma, and Szemerédi [KMS98], who gave a deterministic O(*n* log *n*)-time algorithm.  This is optimal for the reason which you stated in the question.

[ABF+94]  Noga Alon, Manuel Blum, Amos Fiat, Sampath Kannan, Moni Naor, and Rafail Ostrovsky.  Matching nuts and bolts.  In *Proceedings of the Fifth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms (SODA ’94)*, pp. 690–696, 1994.  http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=314673

[KMS98] János Komlós, Yuan Ma, and Endre Szemerédi.  Matching nuts and bolts in O(*n* log *n*) time.  *SIAM Journal on Discrete Mathematics*, 11(3):347–372, 1998.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0895480196304982